# Out of Memory when using Golang method in Python

Tags: python-2.7, go

I have been following this
https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf

Now, what I am doing is:-

- Pass a Json String
- Use Json Unmarshall with a Go Struct Reference & the string
- Do Business Logic & Operations
- Marshal the struct to JSON String
- Return

Now, the issue I am facing is that I am getting an `Out-of-Memory` exception when running it through python. If I run it through normal Go, then it works good.

Also if I dont unmarshal and just initialize the structure normally then I do not have an issue, and get a json string back. But I need to pass a structured data between both.

The issue occurs in the Unmarshal Line

```
func BuildCRMLinkFromJSON(jsonstring string) CRMLinkBO {
    var crmLink CRMLink = CRMLink{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstring), &crmLink)
    var clb = CRMLinkBO{crmLink: crmLink}
    return clb
}
```

The runtime error is:

```
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 140328041390080-byte block (66781184 in use)
fatal error: out of memory
```

or

```
Shauryas-MacBook-Pro:go-python-interfacing xuryax$ python pythonclient.py 
unexpected fault address 0x210c1a334
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x210c1a334 pc=0x1087b0c75]
```

Minimal Reproduce:
`usego.go`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

import "C"

// Data Model

type CustomField struct {
    Field string `json:"field"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type PersonDetails struct {
    Person_id string        `json:"person_id"`
    Detail    []CustomField `json:"detail"`
}

func New(pid string) PersonDetails {
    var p = PersonDetails{"HARDCODED PID IN GO", []CustomField{}}
    return p
}

func BuildFromJSON(jsonString string) PersonDetails {
    var person_detail PersonDetails = PersonDetails{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &person_detail)
    return person_detail
}

func ConvertToJSON(p PersonDetails) string {
    fmt.Println(p)
    var je, _ = json.Marshal(p)
    return string(je)
}

func AddValue(p PersonDetails) PersonDetails {
    var CustField = CustomField{"Hardcoded Field in Go", "Hardcoded Value in Gos"}
    p.Detail = append(p.Detail, CustField)
    return p
}

//export DoJSONOperation
func DoJSONOperation(jsonString string) *C.char {
    var p = BuildFromJSON(jsonString)
    p = AddValue(p)
    var nstr = ConvertToJSON(p)
    return C.CString(nstr)
}

//export DoNormalOperation
func DoNormalOperation(jsonString string) *C.char {
    var p = New(jsonString)
    p = AddValue(p)
    var nstr = ConvertToJSON(p)
    fmt.Println("Before Return: ", string(nstr))
    return C.CString(nstr)
}

func main() {
    // DO noting
    // var jsonStr = `{"person_id":"JsonID","detail":[{"field":"json passed field", "value":"json passed value"}]}`
}
```

PythonClient.py

```
from ctypes import *
import json

def main():
    lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("/Users/xuryax/work/repos/research/go-python-interfacing/usego.so")

    lib.DoJSONOperation.argtypes = [c_char_p]
    lib.DoJSONOperation.restype = c_char_p

    json_string = """{"person_id":"PythonJsonID","detail":[{"field":"json passed field", "value":"json passed value"}]}"""
    normal_pid = "Python ID"
    updated_json = lib.DoNormalOperation(normal_pid)

    print(updated_json)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Weird thing I found in if I use the one with hardcoded it is returning Pointer(integer) but On my previous experiment, I did get a string back.

Comment: you should try to simplify your question by including  minimal complete code ... something we can execute to exhibit the issue ...     How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
    https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you sure jsonstring is what you think it is? The stack trace indicates that it's the byte slice conversion that attempts to allocate 130ish *terra* bytes of memory. An mcve would certainly help a lot.

Comment: Added a minimum code . Yea thats what was weird that it was trying to allocatee 130 TB :S

Comment: I think its a memory leak of something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems quite simple actually. It is a problem with typecasting which I missed.

The method should accept `*C.char`

```
//export DoJSONOperation
func DoJSONOperation(jsonString *C.char) *C.char {
    var GoString = C.GoString(jsonString)
    var p = BuildFromJSON(GoString)
    p = AddValue(p)
    var nstr = ConvertToJSON(p)
    return C.CString(nstr)
}
```

And this seems to solve the problem.

In Python we need to typecast as well. And instead of sending Python String we need to send.
`c_char_p(jsonString)`